# RxJS Observables - How to condition observable returns

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am new to Observables and RxJs and I want to condition the return. If the first selector returns a certain value I want an observable from the second selector. But if the first selector does not return that particular value I want to return false instead (of(false)). I have come this far but this returns an Observable<Observable>. It shouldn't be nested. How do I do this? Here is the code this far:

```
       const condition$: Observable<boolean> =
        this.store.pipe(
            select(this.firstSelector.get()),
            map(item=> {
                if (item !== X) {
                    return of(false)
                } else {
                    return this.store.pipe(select(this.secondSelector.hasValue()))
                }
            })
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. You should be using a higher order mapping operator like `switchMap` to return an observable. `map` is used to transform and return data from the observable.

```js
const condition$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.pipe(
  select(this.firstSelector.get()),
  switchMap(item =>
    (item !== X)
      ? of(false)
      : this.store.pipe(select(this.secondSelector.hasValue()));
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

So if you want to use if-else construct like in your snippet you can do the following

```js
 const condition$: Observable<boolean> =
        this.store.pipe(
            select(this.firstSelector.get()),
            switchMap(item=> {
                if (item !== X) {
                    return of(false)
                } else {
                    return this.store.pipe(select(this.secondSelector.hasValue()))
                }
            })
        )
```

The `switchMap` operator will return a new observable.

Another way of using if-else would be with the partition operator

```js
const condition$ = this.store.pipe(select(this.firstSelector.get()))
            

const [_differentItem$, _sameItems$] = partition(condition$, (item) => item !== X);

const differentItem$ = _differentItem$.pipe(mapTo(false))
const sameItem$ = _differentItem$.pipe(switchMap(() => this.store.pipe(select(this.secondSelector.hasValue()))
```

In the second example partition operator will create two observables where the first one (`_differentItem$`) will emit when the condition evaluetes to true and the second one (`_sameItems`) when it evaluates to `false`

After that I'am creating two pipe-chains that contain the rest of the logic, in the case of the `differentItem$` im directly using the `mapTo` operator which will map all values emiited trough it to `false` and for the second observable `sameItem$` I'm saying whenver your source emits (e.g. trough the stream passes `item === X`) return new observable that is pointing to the secondSelector.